# execute bash command depending on keyword

Tags: bash

I am trying to to provide a file for my shell as an input which in return should test if the file contains a specific word and decide what command to execute. I am not figuring out yet where the mistake might lie. Please find the shell script that i wrote:

```
#!/bin/(shell)

input_file="$1"

output_file="$2"

grep "val1" | awk -f ./path/to/script.awk $input_file > $output_file

grep "val2" | sh ./path/to/script.sh $input_file > $output_file
```

when I input the the file that uses awk everything get executed as expected, but for the second command I don't even get an output file. Any help is much appreciated
Cheers,

Comment: Your `grep` commands aren't being passed a file, so these commands should block indefinitely as `grep` processes `stdin`.  Also, `|` is not a "or" command, it's a pipe that sends the ouptut of the command on the left to the input of the command on the right, and it's probably useful to show us the actual shell you're using instead of `(shell)`, though the `bash` tag is probably a good clue

Comment: Thanks for noticing that. I corrected it and it is working!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You haven't specified this in your question, but I'm guessing you have a file with the keyword, e.g. file `cmdfile` that contains `x-g301`. And then you run your script like:

```
./script "input_file" "output_file" < cmdfile
```

If so, the first `grep` command will consume the whole `cmdfile` on `stdin` while searching for the first pattern, and nothing will be left for the second `grep`. That's why the second `grep`, and then your second script, produces no output.

There are many ways to fix this, but choosing the right one depends on what exactly you are trying to do, and how does that `cmdfile` look like. Assuming that's a larger file with other things than just the command pattern, you could pass that file as a third argument to your script, like this:

```
./script "input_file" "output_file" "cmdfile"
```

And have your script handle it like this:

```
#!/bin/bash

input_file="$1"
output_file="$2"
cmdfile="$3"

if grep -q "X-G303" "$cmdfile"; then
    awk -f ./mno/script.awk "$input_file" > t1.json
fi

if grep -q "x-g301" "$cmdfile"; then
    sh ./mno/tm.sh "$input_file" > t2.json
fi
```

Here I'm also assuming that your `awk` and `sh` scripts don't really need the output from `grep`, since you're giving them the name of the input file.

Note the proper way to use `grep` for existence search is via its exit code (and the muted output with `-q`). Instead of the `if` we could have used shortcircuiting (`grep ... && awk ...`), but this way is probably more readable.

Comment: Thanks for the declaration. Please take a look at the cmdfile I am trying to execute.

Comment: Thanks, I noticed that I performed grep without specifying the source file. everything is working just fine.